# What is the recommended number of Magento attribute option labels?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have a store that has many attributes , especially the brand attribute which has more than 2000 brands & more will be there in the future .
Is it a good practice to have this much attribute labels under an attribute ? I just want to know the side-effects  of the large number of attribute labels .

The things i faced so far was with the following vars (increased the values already):

> the `max_input_vars` , `post_max_size` etc.

Personally I dont like to see the huge list in the page.Even the web page itself will freeze for few moments .

I really need some advice. The store is built on ***Magento 1.9 CE*** planning to upgrade to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_max_size` = for me, **2 Go** (for Big projects) otherwise, `post_max_size` must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`

`max_input_vars` = There is recommended or proper value, it depends on the size and complexity of your configuration.

See [Magento Help Center](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034599631-PHP-settings-errors)

Comment: OMG i was never expecting 2 G !! anyway just want to know one more thing . is this a good practice to have max_input_vars to be > 2000

Comment: Yes, you can, once again, it depends on the project if it is big or not,  you can very well put `post_max_size` = 32M